# Reverse an animation when vimeo video is done playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a video module that uses a splash screen and on click, reveals a full screen video for screen sizes 667 +. I would like to have this reverse it's animation after ending the video so it returns to the splash screen. I'm not really sure where to even start or whether this is possible. Any help is appreciated!

```
    $(function(){

    var $parent = $('.video-hero'),
            $video = $parent.find('iframe'),
            $playButton = $(".play"),
            $itemsToFadeOut = $(".vid-cap, .ghost"),
            f = $video[0],
            url = $video.attr('src').split('?')[0],
            activeVideoClass = "video-started";

            // setup fitVids
            $parent.fitVids();

            // handle play click
            $playButton.click(function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                // grab height of video
                var videoHeight = $video.height();

                // add class to hero when video is triggered
                $parent.addClass(activeVideoClass);

                // fade out the play button
                $(this).fadeOut("fast");

                // fade out poster image, overlay, and heading
                $itemsToFadeOut.fadeOut();

                // toggle accessibility features
                $video.attr({
                    "aria-hidden" : "false",
                    "tabindex" : "0"
                });

                // set focus to video for accessibility control
                $video.focus();

                // set height of hero based on height of video
                $parent.css("max-height",videoHeight).height(videoHeight);

                // send play command to Vimeo api
                runCommand('play');

            });

            // send play to vimeo api
            var runCommand = function(cmd){
                var data = {method : cmd};
                f.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
            }

            // handle resize
            $(window).resize(function(){
                var videoHeight = $video.height();
                if($(".video-started").size() === 1){
                    $parent.height(videoHeight);
                }
            });

});
```

Remember to resize my **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wejmkcx4/)** so you're able to see the animation I am talking about.

Comment: check this https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api

Comment: The full screen is not displaying in Firefox Browser.

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra it is being blocked in FF from JSFiddle, but our website's domain plays it fine, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @maioman, i've looked through there and I still can't get it to recognize the video ending?

Comment: @user4875251, ahem, find `addEventListener` on that page and below is a table listing the events including `finish`, which appears to be what you need.

Comment: @wOxxOm
Using froogaloop and the finish listener, still doesn't recognize. http://jsfiddle.net/wejmkcx4/6/

Comment: Your code references `video` but I don't see where you define it. There's only `$video`. And does jQuery have `.addEvent()` method? Did you mean `.on()`?

Comment: @wOxxOm I see.. hmm, swapped it out to `$video.on()` but still won't trigger the alert on finish?

Comment: Well, I would try to use vimeo API *exactly* as it's defined in the docs, that is via vanilla js.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out everyone! I'll explain each chunk of code step by step for anyone's future reference.

I was able to accomplish what I needed to do without the froogaloop cdn, and just using [fitvids.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fitvids/1.0.3/jquery.fitvids.min.js) here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wejmkcx4/17/) of my solutions.

I listed all of my JS below in sections, but for the answer to my question of "reversing my function after video finishes" you will only need to pay attention to my **Event Handlers**, **Connection to the API**, and **Player State Functions**. Once I was able to make the connection and read that the video was ended, I used `addClass();` and `removeClass();` coupled with CSS `Transitions` to handle swapping between my *play* and *ready(post finish)* states.

I tried to document and explain as much as I could so hopefully this can help someone in the future!

### Naming my Vars

Not much to mention here, this is just the preliminary, the main thing to pay attention to is `var url` it's the only way I could write it to allow me to use my listeners with the Vimeo api.

```
var parent = $('.video-hero'), 
                 f = $('iframe'),
                 $playButton = $(".play"),
                 $itemsToFadeOut = $(".vid-cap, .ghost, .play"),
                 $video = f[0],
                 url = f.attr('src').split('?')[0],
                 activeVideoClass = "video-started", //Class for when video is playing
           standardClass = "standard"; //Class for when video is finished/before play
```

### Event Listeners / Handlers

My listeners just wait to receive a message from the api/player of whether the video is `ready`, `paused`, `finished` or `play`ing.

*listeners*

```
// Listen for messages from the player
if (window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
}
else {
    window.attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived, false);
}
```

My handlers well... handle when my functions are fired. My functions are located below, this just lets me choose which state (case) I have being sent from the API and how to react to it.

*handlers*

```
// Handle messages received from the player
function onMessageReceived(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    switch (data.event) {
        //Ready case is before play / after finish
            case 'ready':
            onReady();
            break;

        case 'pause':
            onPause();
            break;

        case 'finish':
            onFinish();
            break;
    }
}
```

### Connecting to the Vimeo API

This section communicates hand in hand with my html `play` button and vimeo's api/player, allowing me to run, pause and stop the video

```
// send play to vimeo api
            var runCommand = function(cmd){
                var data = {method : cmd};
                f[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
            }


// Helper function for sending a message to the player
function post(action, value) {
    var data = { method: action };

    if (value) {
        data.value = value;
    }

    f[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), url);
}
```

### Player State Functions

What will happen based on which state or case the player is in

```
function onReady() {
    post('addEventListener', 'finish');

}

  function onPause() {
    console.log('paused');
}

function onFinish() {
  // add class to hero when video is triggered
                parent.removeClass(activeVideoClass);
parent.addClass(standardClass);
                // fade out the play button
                $(this).fadeIn("slow");
                // fade out poster image, overlay, and heading
                $itemsToFadeOut.fadeIn();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

To detect the end of the video, and run JS code, you might need to make use of the Froogaloop library:

https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#universal-with-froogaloop

You can then do something like:

```
var player = $f(iframe[0]);

player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('finish', function() {
        // Animation...
    });
});
```

The different events are here:
https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#events

I do this on a site I built recently in order to close the modal window on video end / finish: 
http://billy.fm/

Feel free to examine the JS code there (unminified version): 
http://billy.fm/wp-content/themes/billy/js/main.js

Wish I had more time to help you, but this should set you off on the right track.

Comment: I've had this already, but I am having trouble getting it to track the finish.

Comment: I tried using this and was getting an `'iframe is undefined` error so I converted it to `var player = $f('iframe');` which cleared the error but still not firing an alert when video is completed. :/

Comment: I'll try to update this further once I have enough time in the next day. Good luck.

Comment: I finally figured out how to get it to read that the video was ended, now I just need to reverse my animations.